# Search email addresses in pcap

Tags: parsing, smtp, imap, pop3

I have an idea of program that should search email addresses in correspondingly tags "mail from", "rcpt to", "to", "from" of smtp, imap and pop3 protocols. I'm interested in only those tags, and no any other.

I used ngrep, but i couldn't write an regexp to search an email between other emails (in case of multiple addresses in "to" tag).

The solution i found was to open the pcap files one by one using fopen and search with memmem for the tags mentioned above. Then i would parse that string to separate the address from aliases, in some cases. The problem is that i have a lot of files needed to be parsed, so i don't have the time necessary to open files, allocate memory, read, search and retrieve email addresses and delete the files after processing.

My question is that are there any other robust and fast methods for c or c++ to get these email addreses or could you help me to write the regex to match addresses like this?

I could find that the "To" tag could have strings like this after it:
To: "Some Name" some.name@domain.com, Some Other , johndoe@somewhere.in,

Comment: You can achieve something similar on the command line by using tshark: `tshark -r smtp.pcap -Y 'smtp.req.command == "RCPT"' -T fields -e smtp.req.parameter`. Perhaps there's a way to link to a Wireshark library to achieve that in C or C++...

Comment: @legoscia, thanks, but the problem is that this filter is not case insensitive and does not resolve the problem for imap and pop3

Comment: For case insensitive matches, use something like `matches "(?i)rcpt"` as described in [the wireshark-filter man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html). For IMAP and POP3, look them up in the [Display Filter Reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/).